# Can't boot ubuntu anymore... and I meddled

Tags: boot, nvidia, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS a few days ago on my brand new Dell Inspiron 7620 equipped with a dedicated nvidia geforce RTi 3050 gpu.
Everything worked well... until I wanted to install virtual box.
I did install virtual box, but upon restarting the laptop, I got asked about MOK stuff I didn't understand.

Virtualbox warned me about the MOK manipulation to add keys on restart, and told me to remember the password I set at the end of virtualbox installation, and I think I managed to pass this step (Im not sure because I typed the password as an azerty user at first, and then as I was in qwerty, and it seemed to work because I didn't have an error anymore)

Here start the problems.
At boot, I got an error about `dell_smm_hwmon: unable to get SMM Dell signature`

I thought my problem was with MOK keys. My google searchs lead me to clear the TMP owner information from the BIOS (there's an option for that), but it still didn't work

Then, I found out the error was possible related to unstable nvidia drivers. So I managed to boot my system using the root terminal from the grub recovery tools, and use an older version of nvidia drivers

Then, on reboot, I got a new error message (probably due to my wrongling clearing the TMP thing) saying `UUID=xxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell`. This made me sad. There I tried to set the storage boot option from Raid on to AHCI/NVMe, because I found a post that said to do so.

Now, I have no errors showing up on boot, just "pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid" and then another black screen with just a blinking "_" from which I can switch to a console using alt-f4 on which I can type my ubuntu session username and password to login, but just in a terminal.

I also tried to deactivate / activate virtualization stuff to no avail and use a boot-repair utility from a livecd but it didn't work...

So there, I did a lot of stuff I didn't understand and now I'm desperate...
If anyone knows how to fix this mess, I'd be really grateful !

Comment: Disable secure boot on UEFI make sure you can still boot Windows. I assume the computer came with Windows and  you still have it. Then start over.

Comment: @NNmath all the stuff I did I described in the original post
I could try to reinstall everything but I'm worried my problem is "deeper" than os level ?

Comment: On my Dell 5310 worked without issue with 22.04 and RAID on. I did have to have Windows bitlocker & fast start up off. And Dell updated UEFI to latest firmware. Similar on 3520: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1543006&page=182&p=14097006#post14097006 If nVidia chose safe boot & install optional restricted drivers to get correct nVidia driver installed.